# Why would Lance work here if he didn't need the money?

Tags: plot-explanation, detectorists

In *Detectorists*, Lance's day job is at some sort of vegetable warehouse facility. The work seems to be poorly paid, menial, and Lance is not especially respected by his colleagues.

However, it is revealed in Series 1 Episode #5 that:

> Lance in fact won a large sum from the National Lottery around the time that his wife left him.

So if Lance doesn't really need the money, why continue to work at the warehouse facility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He won £300,000, which isn't that large a sum. Assuming he'd need £1000 per month to merely "survive" (rent + food etc.), that money would run out in 25 years or so. And that isn't counting the fact that money is worth less over time, plus that he could encounter a costly accident.

Comment: considering he can live ~25 years with the money he won, why he couldn't quit the menial job for now, enjoy life and go back to another job when or **if** he needed?

Comment: Toby Jones is 50 or so, and I guess that's also approx. the age of his character. 50 + 25 = 75. Who's gonna hire a 75 year old? (Also, I doubt £1000 is enough to live on.)

Comment: thats why I meant **if**. he can live on lottery money, with some savings, he can live on it until the end I think.

Comment: @Vishwa The current average age in the UK is 79 year. Again, that is assuming you can live on £1000 and never encounter any major issue that can cost you a lot of money. IMHO even winning £1 million would not be enough for him to stop working and live comfortably for the rest of his life without a worry.

Comment: @Vishwa See also: https://www.thisismoney.co.uk/money/pensions/article-1681664/How-much-do-I-need-to-quit-work-forever.html which says "£684,000 to fund 40 years (retire at age 50)" but also points out "these cash flows include no allowance for unexpected longevity" plus you need to put in a lot of work to manage that money. "For an income of £25,000 in perpetuity, using a 2% real return you would need a fund of £1,250,000." But then there is inflation, unexpected expenses, etc.

Comment: yeah.. it's not enough to cover everything. but it will be if he manages to invest it and keep a steady income over the years, make better decisions etc.. 

Agree with what you said is the reality

Comment: @BCdotWEB with a simple lifestyle it is definitely possible to live on £1000 a month - we know he lives in a small flat in rural Essex where housing can be relatively cheap so, if he owns it, he could easily have paid off the mortgage by now.  We know he saves money on groceries by taking vegetables from work and he's not interested in luxuries like new cars (but this could be a false economy with his Triumph).  But, I agree 300K is not quite enough to safely retire on, so he'd want to claim a state pension which means paying national insurance which means working (same with a private pension)